# Bring focus back to terminal window that called command

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Say I have a terminal command (such as a make target) that opens a browser window (on a mac):

```
open http://localhost:3000/
```

By default, that `open` opens a browser window and now we're focused on the browser window. Is there a way instead to keep the focus on the current terminal window? (or bring the focus back to the terminal window somehow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `-g` option to `open` (although I don't know what mnemonic `g` is supposed to represent):

> -g  Do not bring the application to the foreground.

So you can simply use

```
open -g http://localhost:3000/
```